# What is the correct way to split chunk in webpack4

Tags: webpack

I have three files: `index.js`, `foo.js` and `bar.js`. Below is their content:

```js
/** index.js */
import foo from './foo'
import bar from './bar'
// ...
/** foo.js */
export default function foo () {/* some code */}
// ....
/** bar.js */
import lodash from 'lodash'
export default function bar () {/* some code using lodash */}
```

My goal is to get outputs like this using webpack:

```
main.89sfds.js // the entry
runtime~main.dfsdf78.js // webpack runtime
vendors~main.90fsd0fs.js // lodash
foo.dfjiusdf.js // bundle foo module
bar.89sdfsdfs.js // bundle bar module
```

So I try to use this config file:

```js
module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: true,
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      cacheGroups: {
        foo: {
          test: path.resolve('src/foo.js'),
          name: 'foo',
          enforced: true
        },
        bar: {
          test: path.resolve('src/bar.js'),
          name: 'bar',
          enforced: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However the output becomes:

```
main.4f34rwf.js // the entry
runtime~main.sf24fds.js // webpack runtime
foo.sf4df3e.js // bundle foo module
bar.4389sfd.js // bundle bar module
```

As you see, the `vendor` is missing(which is included in main.js now)

Seems if I just try to bundle one module, `foo.js` or `bar.js`, the `vendor` appears.

So how can I get the right output?

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. Quite a simple reason.

Just set `optimization.splitChunks.maxInitialRequests` to a bigger value, which is 4 by default.